# Import variable time series data in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, time-series

I've looked for a solution to this here on stack overflow and elsewhere, but can't find examples that deal with the volume I have to work with. If I have missed a solution to this that has been posted elsewhere, I'd be very grateful if someone could point me into the right direction.

I'm trying to import time series data from 45 different Excel worksheets (about 5 per Excel workbook). Each worksheet contains commodity price series, covering several years of daily prices for each commodity.

The raw Excel data has one row for each day for which prices might exist and one column for each commodity contract, which typically is a monthly future contract. The points for each contract hence are at least 30 each (but not much more) while the entire table has several thousand rows and 100+ columns.
I was able to build a SSIS package that reads the data and using unpivot, transforms the matrix into row based records with columns for:

```
Date, Price, Contract
```

The problem however is that in the unpivot transform I have to manually specify the destination column for each transformed input column. So 45 worksheets, each containing 100+ columns (some even several hundred) for contracts I'd be ending up 'hard-coding' those transforms manually for the next few days... On top, this is not as flexible/re-usable as I was hoping.

Example of the raw data attached (the entire Cocoa worksheet contains 9724 rows and 195 columns)

[image: Example raw data]

Here's how the unpivot for another single commodity is configured. The 'Destination Column' has to be filled in manually row-by-row.

[image]

I'm hoping that I have just missed the right steps in the unpivot configuration to make these columns dynamic. Ideally the SSIS solution can be re-used with equally formatted Excel workbooks later again. It's not required to run this on the Server as it's not a frequently recurring thing but rather once or twice per year max. So i can easily kick this off manually from within VS.

I'm trying to help an academic researcher who would otherwise spend a massive amount of time cleaning and analysing the data manually in Excel.

Comment: So, why not write a dynamic unpivot script and then use it as a Script Component in the Data Flow?

Comment: I guess when a new commodity arrives or is removed, your columns change? SSIS isn't going to like that. Can you indicate how likely the columns are to change, and are they different between worksheets/workbooks? This might be a job for BIML. Although I have never done it, in theory that's what BIML is good for - dynamically creating packages based on your source data.

Comment: @Ralph : can a script deal with variable column numbers and names over a large set of excel worksheets? do you know of any examples that i can look at?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: The files are static, they're not going to change but are of variable structure. each has a different set of column names and numbers. BIML sounds like a whole new language to learn - unfortunately i have little time to complete this... :(

Comment: Just to clarify: I have the target db structure and managed without problems to import the data from a single worksheet using the standard unpivot transaction. I have also covered the loops to cycle through workbooks and worksheets. I just need to be able to dynamically unpivot the data.
Thanks for all the input so far!

Comment: You could also use dynamic SQL to perform the unpivot. You import all of the excel files into identical staging tables then you run some dynamic SQL over them to unpivot it. This basically puts the logic into SQL rather than BIML or SSIS.

Comment: @Olaf D - Did you resolve your import in the end?

Comment: @Mike Not dynamically, no. I ran out of time and manually configured all the 45 unpivot transforms in the end. So almost 4 million price records have been imported now but the solution I created is unfortunately not reusable.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this as a series of nested loops:

**Loop 1**, iterate through all files in the folder. pass the file name to next loop

**Loop 2** Open File, Iterate through sheets

**Loop 3** in sheet X, Loop through the columns (A)  > 1

**Loop 4** - Loop through rows:

Read sheet X, Row B,

Get values from (**Row B, Column 1**) as Date,  (**Row 1, Column A**) as Product. (**Row B, Column A**) as Price - write to destination.

End Loop 4
(optional, at the end of the column record some meta data about number of rows )

End of Loop 3
(optional, record some meta data about the number of columns in the sheet)

End of Loop 2
(optional, record some meta data about the number of sheets in file X)

End of Loop 1
(strongly suggested - record some meta data about the file X and number of sheets/rows/columns - you can test a sample later for your own confidence)

You may want to modify a copy of one of your files so that you can test for issues.

- sheet empty
- invalid data
- missing header
- text instead of price

This will give more confidence and will shorten the rework that is required when you discover new edge cases.

Final output table should be the denormalised data in 3 columns:

```
Date, 

Product, 

Price
```

**EDIT**
Here is a link that shows how you can dynamically loop through the columns of an Excel spreadsheet (and sheets) so that you can use this process to unpivot the data to a normalised form

[Looping through Excel columns in SSIS](http://cr9itesh.blogspot.com/2013/05/loop-through-column-field-names-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to design and create the tables that are going to receive the data and experiment with some manual data entry to check the data model.

Make sure each spreadsheet has enough header information to know how to process the rows.

When that is done, I would save the sheets to text files with tab delimiters.

Next I would write a loading program in Perl. It reads the header rows first and determines the rules for inserting the rows into the database. Then each row gets converted into an insert into the database.

Here is an example from an invoice loading program I own (all rights):

```
if ($first) {
    $obj->_hdr2keys(0); # convert spreadhseet header into a lookup
    my $hdr = $obj->_copystruct($obj->{ar}[0]);
    my @Hhdr = ('invoice header id');
    my @Hcols = ('invhid');
    my @Htypes = ('serial');
    my @Dhdr = ('invoice detail id');
    my @Dcols = ('invdid','invhid');
    my @Dtypes = ('serial','integer');
    for (my $col=0; $col <= $#{$hdr}; $col++) {
    my $colname = lc($obj->_pomp($hdr->[$col]));
    if ($colname eq 'invoicenumber') {
        push @Hhdr, $hdr->[$col];
        push @Hcols, $colname;
        push @Htypes, 'char(32)';
    }
    elsif ($colname eq 'buysell') {
        push @Hhdr, $hdr->[$col];
        push @Hcols, $colname;
        push @Htypes, 'boolean';
        }
    elsif ($colname eq 'suppliercustomer') {
        push @Hhdr, $hdr->[$col];
        push @Hcols, $colname;
        push @Htypes, 'char(64)';
        }
    elsif ($colname eq 'date') {
        push @Hhdr, 'Transaction Date';
        push @Hcols, 'transactiondate';
        push @Htypes, 'date';
        }
    elsif ($colname eq 'article') {
        push @Dhdr, 'Article id';
        push @Dcols, 'artid';
        push @Dtypes, 'integer';
        push @Dhdr, 'Article Description';
        push @Dcols, 'description';
        push @Dtypes, 'char(64)';
        }
    elsif ($colname eq 'qty') {
        push @Dhdr, $hdr->[$col];
        push @Dcols, $colname;
        push @Dtypes, 'integer';
    }
    elsif ($colname eq 'priceexclbtw') {
        push @Dhdr, $hdr->[$col];
        push @Dcols, $colname;
        push @Dtypes, 'double precision';
        }
    elsif ($colname eq 'btw') {
        push @Dhdr, $hdr->[$col];
        push @Dcols, $colname;
        push @Dtypes, 'real';
        }
    }
    $obj->_getset('INVHar',
    ['invoiceheader',
     ['PK','invhid'],
     ['__COLUMNS__'],
     \@Hcols,
     \@Htypes,
     \@Hhdr
    ]
    );

    $obj->_getset('INVDar',
    ['invoicedetail',
     ['PK','invdid'],
     ['FK','invhid','invoiceheader','invhid'],
     ['FK','artid','article','artid'],
     ['__COLUMNS__'],
     \@Dcols,
     \@Dtypes,
     \@Dhdr
    ]
    );
}
$first = 0;

SALESROW: for (my $i=1; $i <= $#{$obj->{ar}}; $i++) {
    my @Hrow = ('');
    my @Drow = ('');
    my $date = $obj->_selectar('', $i, 'Date');
    $date =~ s/\-/\//g;
    if ($date) {
    $obj->_validCSV('date', $date)
        or die "CSV format error date |$date| in file $file";
    }
    my $invtotal = ($obj->_selectar('', $i, 'Invoice Total incl. BTW'));
    my $article = $obj->_selectar('', $i, 'Article');
    $date or $article or next SALESROW;
    if ($date) {
    push @Hrow, $obj->_selectar('', $i, 'Invoice Number');
    my $buysell = $obj->_selectar('', $i, 'Buy/Sell');
    push @Hrow, ($buysell eq 'S') ? 1 : 0;
    push @Hrow, $obj->_selectar('', $i, 'Supplier/Customer');
    push @Hrow, $date;
    push @{$obj->_getset('INVHar')}, \@Hrow;
    $invhid++;
    }
    push @Drow, $invhid;
    if ($article eq 'E0154') {
    push @Drow, 1;
    }
    elsif ($article eq 'C0154') {
    push @Drow, 2;
    }
    elsif ($article eq 'C0500') {
    push @Drow, 3;
    }
    elsif ($article eq 'C2000') {
    push @Drow, 4;
    }
    elsif ($article eq 'C5000') {
    push @Drow, 5;
    }
    else {
        die "unrecognised sales article $article\n"
      . Dumper($obj->{ar}[$i]);
    }
    push @Drow, undef; # description is in article table
    push @Drow, $obj->_selectar('', $i, 'Qty.');
    push @Drow, $obj->_selectar('', $i, 'Price excl. BTW');
    push @Drow, $obj->_selectar('', $i, 'BTW %');
    push @{$obj->_getset('INVDar')}, \@Drow;
}
```

This creates header and detail records for invoices after the product table has already been loaded from another spreadsheet.

In the above example two array of arrays are created, INVHar and INVDar. When they are ready, the calling routine loads them into the database as follows. In this next code example the tables are created as well as the rows and also a metadb is updated for loading of future tables and managing foreign keys for existing tables. The array created in the previous snippet contains all information needed to create the table and insert the rows. There is also a simple routine _DBdatacnv that converts between the formats in the spreadsheet and the formats needed in the database. For example, the spreadsheet had currency symbols that need to be stripped before insertion.

```
sub _arr2db {
my ($obj) = @_;
my $ar = $obj->_copystruct($obj->_getset('ar'));
my $dbh = $obj->_getset('CDBh');
my $mdbh = $obj->_getset('MDBh');
my $table = shift @$ar;
$mdbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;

my @tables = $mdbh->selectrow_array(
    "SELECT id FROM mtables
     WHERE name = \'$table\'"
);
my $id = $tables[0] || '';
if ($id) {
$mdbh->do("DELETE FROM mcolumns where tblid=$id");
$mdbh->do("DELETE FROM mtables where id=$id");
}
# process constraints
my %constraint;
while ($#{$ar} >= 0
  and $ar->[0][0] ne '__COLUMNS__') {
my $cts = shift @$ar;
my $type = shift @$cts;
if ($type eq 'PK') {
    my $pk = shift @$cts;
    $constraint{$pk} ||= '';
    $constraint{$pk} .= ' PRIMARY KEY';
    @$cts and die "unsupported compound key for $table";
}
elsif ($type eq 'FK') {
    my ($col, $ft, $fk) = @$cts;
    $ft && $fk or die "incomplete FK declaration in CSV for $table";
    $constraint{$col} ||= '';
    $constraint{$col} .=
        sprintf( ' REFERENCES %s(%s)', $ft, $fk );
}
elsif ($type eq 'UNIQUE') {
    while (my $uk = shift @$cts) {
    $constraint{$uk} ||= '';
    $constraint{$uk} .= ' UNIQUE';
    }
}
elsif ($type eq 'NOT NULL') {
    while (my $nk = shift @$cts) {
    $constraint{$nk} ||= '';
    $constraint{$nk} .= ' NOT NULL';
    }
}
else {
    die "unrecognised constraint |$type| for table $table";
}
}
shift @$ar;
unless ($mdbh->do("INSERT INTO mtables (name) values (\'$table\')")) {
warn $mdbh->errstr . ": mtables";
$mdbh->rollback;
die;
}
@tables = $mdbh->selectrow_array(
    "SELECT id FROM mtables
     WHERE name = \'$table\'"
);
$id = shift @tables;
$dbh->do("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table CASCADE")
    or die $dbh->errstr;
my $create = "CREATE TABLE $table\n";
my $cols = shift @$ar;
my $types = shift @$ar;
my $desc = shift @$ar;
my $first = 1;
my $last = 0;
for (my $i=0; $i<=$#{$cols}; $i++) {
$last = 1;
if ($first) {
    $first = 0;
    $create .= "( "
}
else {
    $create .= ",\n";
}
$create .= $cols->[$i]
    . ' ' . $obj->_DBcnvtype($types->[$i]);
$constraint{$cols->[$i]}
  and $create .= ' ' . $constraint{$cols->[$i]};
unless ($mdbh->do("INSERT INTO mcolumns (tblid,name,type,description)
    values ($id,\'$cols->[$i]\',\'$types->[$i]\',\'$desc->[$i]\')"))
{
    warn $mdbh->errstr;
    $mdbh->rollback;
    die;
}
}
$last and $create .= ')';
unless ($dbh->do($create)) {
    warn $dbh->errstr;
    $dbh->rollback;
    die;
}
my $count = 0;
while (my $row = shift @$ar) {
$count++;
my $insert = "INSERT INTO $table (";
my $values = 'VALUES (';
my $first = 1;
for (my $i=0; $i<=$#{$cols}; $i++) {
    my $colname = $cols->[$i];
    unless (defined($constraint{$colname})
      and $constraint{$colname} =~ /PRIMARY KEY/) {
    if ($first) {
        $first = 0;
    }
    else {
        $insert .= ', ';
        $values .= ', ';
    }
    $insert .= $colname;
    my $val = $obj->_DBdatacnv('CSV', 'DB',
        $types->[$i],$row->[$i]);
    if ($val eq '%ABORT') {
        $mdbh->rollback;
        die;
    }
    $values .= $val;
    }
}
$insert .= ')' . $values . ')';
unless ($dbh->do($insert)) {
    warn $dbh->errstr;
    warn $insert;
    $mdbh->rollback;
    die;
}
}
NOINSERT: $mdbh->commit;
$dbh->commit;
# warn "inserted $count rows into $table";
}
```

Update: ok I'll add the generic routine that converts from CSV to array ready for _arr2db above for all other cases I have for a system: The spreadsheets are first augmented with PK FK and other constraints followed by a header of column names for the database, a row of the database types (notional, actual are taken care of in _DBcnvdatatype) then a row of tags that go in the metadatabase and finally a token **COLUMNS** just before the rows of data to insert.

```
sub _csv2arr {
my ($obj, $csv ) = @_;
my $ar = [];
my $delim = $obj->_getset('csvdelim') || '\,';
my $basename = basename($csv);
$basename =~ s/\.txt$//;
$ar = [$basename];
open my $fh, $csv
  or die "$!: $csv";
while (<$fh>) {
chomp;
my $sa = [];
@$sa = split /$delim/;
push @$ar, $sa;
}
close $fh;
$obj->{ar} = $ar;
}
```

Comment: incidentally, using postgres I had trouble with the date format, so I adapted _DBdatacnv to convert from DD/MM/YYYY to epoch time and store it in the database as a bigint. But the strategy is clear: map CSV types to chosen database types. My example is a conversion of denormalised invoice line items into normalised tables, but the reverse looks the same given that these routines entirely generic.,